# How to create a property list from nsmutablearray programmatically under resource folder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I have to create a **property list** from `NSMutableArray` programmatically under a valid path, I mean under **resource folder**. So that I can access it whenever there is need. Please help me if somebody knows about it. Also I need to convert that **plist** into `NSMutableArray` so I can use that value. I have searched and tried to do that but have not successful. Thanx in advance !

Comment: You can save it in documents folder !

Comment: Please accept the answer if it's correct by clicking on the check. If it really help you can click the up arrow too!

Answer (score 1):

The entire  App bundle is read-only for iOS apps, therefore you cannot add any resources at runtime. You could use for example the Library/Caches folder for that purpose. See `URLsForDirectory:inDomains:` for locating the path to that directory.

For example:

```
// Path to a plist file in Caches directory:
NSURL *cacheDir = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *plistFile = [cacheDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"myresource.plist"];

// write array to plist file:
[myArray writeToURL:plistFile atomically:NO];

// read array from plist file and make it mutable:
NSMutableArray *secondArray =  [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:plistFile] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: ok....i dont need to create it within resource.....just giving a valid path how to create the plist and store data to it????????thanx for 2nd answer???????

Comment: I have added explicit sample code to my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: @user1523344: Did the sample code help? Then it would be nice if you would "accept" the answer.